# my IIS server does not have MIME Types pan

Tags: windows, iis

I wanted to change the MIME type of my website. Unfortunately, I could not find the MIME type in my IIS manager. Could you please help me out.
The version of my IIS is 6.1
Regards,

Comment: which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: my version is 6.1

Comment: Do you mean the mime type of the file you are returning? What kind of file are you trying to return and what is the programming language you are using? (C#, PHP, etc). E.g. if this was an asp.net page, you'd set the mime-type header at point of download of an unusual file type, e.g. Excel.  Ordinary file types (html, plain text, images) usually just work out of the box.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the( MIME types panel). I don't see it in my IIS manager.

Answer (score 2):

Pick the website, right-click on it and choose Properties.  Click the HTTP Headers tab and at the bottom of the panel is Mime Map.  Click on the File Types button and use the resulting dialog to add file extensions and MIME types.

Commenter is possibly correct, and ServerFault is possibly a better place for questions like this.  But we coders have to worry about this kind of thing often enough, so I don't think it's too far off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you are trying to configure additional MIME types to your sites;

This article should help point in the right direction.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786786(WS.10).aspx

In addition, configuring open IIS manager, select the properties for the node, click MIME types, select new,  extension .pan in the box and enter application/octet-stream in the type box.